# How to join a jQuery toArray() array with a div object?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects returned by `$(this).children().toArray()`;. I want take this array, and do something like `array.join('<div class="joinerItem"></div>')`. However javascript cannot convert html element objects to strings(?). How would I do this?

Edit: let me clarify a bit more. I am taking this array and filtering it. I then have an array like `[HtmlDivElement, HtmlParagraphElement, HtmlBlockquoteElement]`. I want that to become `[HtmlDivElement,  HtmlDivElement, HtmlParagraphElement, HtmlDivElement, HtmlBlockquoteElement]`, where the inserted div elements have a class of 'foo'.

Edit: I solved it. .html() is smart enough to accept an array of strings and DOM Elements.

Comment: It still may not clear enough. May be you should create a demo showing what you've attempted to do and what it is that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make your goal objective clear.
I'm going to attempt to answer your question out of my
assumption of what you want.

If your goal is to wrap each of the returned objects in
an array into the innerHTML of a div named as above, you
can try looping the returned array like the following:

```js
$('something').on("event",function(){
  //Grab your array
    var $localArray = $(this).children().toArray();
    //After setting it as a variable, loop through it. You may need to add ".children()" between var name and .each()
    $($localArray).each(function(){
      //Find all your jonerItem classed elements and update their innerhTML with your div tag + the array values.
      $('.jonerItem').html('<div class="joinerItem">' + this.text() + '</div>');
    //That should work to convert the values in each array into a text value.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newHTMLstr = $(this).children().map(function() {
    return $('<div/>').html( this ).html();
}).get()
.join('<div class="joinerItem"></div>');
```

```js
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    var newHTMLstr = $(this).children().map(function() {
        return $('<div/>').html( this ).html();
    })
    .get()
    .join('<div class="joinerItem"></div>');
  
    console.log( newHTMLstr );
    $(this).html( newHTMLstr );
});
```

```css
.joinerItem {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">
  <div>Child one</div>
  <div>Child two</div>
  <div>Child Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. .html() can accept an array of both strings and HtmlElements.